# Fastest and most efficient way of converting **haml** and **scss** files? (Ruby on Windows)

Tags: windows, ruby, haml, sass

I'm a ruby/haml/sass-beginner. I just installed ruby and rails for windows, haml, and sass (stand alone and plugin for rails).

I know how to convert and **haml** file into a **html** file (and vice versa):

```
haml index.haml > output.html
```

and how to convert a **scss** fiel into a **css** file (and vice versa):

```
sass --watch style.scss:style.css
```

I save more time converting **scss** files because every time I save a **scss** file the corresponding **css** file is automatically updated (i think that's the suppose of the **watch** command)

but for the haml files, I'm still doing it manually (`haml index.haml > output.html`).

I believe there's other ways to save time converting **haml** and **scss** files.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you [setup Rails to work with Haml](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#plugin), then start your development server, the Haml in your views get converted into HTML for you on-the-fly, so there's no need to watch for changes to your Haml separately.

However, if you're creating prototypes using just Haml and SCSS and not using the Rails stack at this stage, then there are a couple of useful tools you can use that automatically render your Haml and SCSS on page refresh:

**Serve**
http://github.com/jlong/serve

**StaticMatic**
http://github.com/staticmatic/staticmatic

Of these two, Serve is easier to use, but is not as powerful as StaticMatic. With Serve, all you need to do is install it (`gem install serve`) and type `serve` at the command line in the directory containing your Haml files. Then point your browser at `http://localhost:4000`. [Full details here](http://github.com/jlong/serve#readme).

You can also hook-up Serve to make use of [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) the Sass meta-framework (which is awesome). There's a [full tutorial here](http://wiseheartdesign.com//articles/2010/06/07/compass-with-serve-and-rack).

Answer (score 0):

Oh, there's also dynamicmatic now too which might be good as well to look into.  Basically similar to staticmatic but with some obvious differences that might be useful. I've used SM quite a lot recently and really like it. Very easy to use, very simple to set up and really does most things I need it to.